# Backing up to two locations at the same time?

Tags: 13.04, backup, usb-drive, deja-dup

I'm using deja-dup to create backups of my documents, but it won't let me backup to two places at once. The backup button is greyed out. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to do this?

`/etc/crontab`

Add a line that copies every so often (or a couple of minutes after the backup is made) files over to that 2nd directory.

An example of this would be:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
# LogRotate
07 01 * * 1-5   root    /u1/bin/LogRotate.pl
```

This will start script `/u1/bin/LogRotate.pl` as root on days 1-5 (monday-friday) at 1:07 AM. 
Similar to this you can create and add a script copying the files made by the backup to a 2nd location.

This also works for commands so in theory this is possible:

```
07 01 * * 1-5   hannibal  cp -rf /usr/tmp/* /tmp/
```

and would copy contents of /usr/tmp/ to /tmp/ including directories and overwrite if the file already exists as user hannibal.

Comment: Should you be running user backups as root? Won't that make the backed up files root owned?

Comment: You can use any user instead of root. That is the idea behind /etc/crontab  ;)

Comment: You should mention to edit the crontab with the `crontab -e` command. The command warns you when you have an invalid entry and doesn't require root. [reference](http://serverfault.com/questions/347318/is-it-bad-to-edit-cron-file-manually)

Comment: No no no. crontab != /etc/crontab crontab -e stores it files elsewhere (/var/spool/cron/) and does -not- support using a user in the command line. Those are 2 different methods.

Comment: The OP shouldn't need to execute it as a different user, because the files being backed up are not system files. `crontab -e` should generally be used for user specific crontabs

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, and probably never will be. A launchpad feature request bug on "multiple profiles for different target locations" is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/324631/comments/15). It is said

> I don't see how this profiles feature fits that focus. Supporting it would add a burden of UI complication, development time, testing time, and maintenance effort as there will most certainly be bugs. These distract from the core focus of offering a simple, first-class backup experience for the 80% use case. The biggest 'competitor' (Apple's Time Machine) does not offer profiles AFAIK.

The request is marked as "Won't Fix"

As a workaround, you could use `rsync` for your backups instead (though it doesn't have multiple versioning) or you could change the target manually.